# Generic Update Row Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Scenario:  Web application, various tables, each table could be updated from various places in the app, not all columns get updated all of the time.

I need a generic stored procedure for a given table which can be used to process updates to a row. I want to build it so that if I am only updating a few columns (of potentially many), then I only send in those few parameters (reducing payload to the db, reducing lines of code, etc). If any parameters are not present then the column doesn't get updated.

Currently, all parameters (e.g. 1 for each column) default to NULL. Then, if the value is NULL, then the column doesn't get updated. If the parameter is not null, e.g. a value was passed, the column is updated with the new value.

Given this, How can I handle instances where the app needs to do an update to a column which currently has a value, but it needs to be set to Null, while still keeping the ability to only pass in parameters for columns which need to change?

I don't want to pass every parameter every time an update needs to occur, for reasons explained above.

Here is what I have. As you can see, currently, if the input value for a column is null, we don't set a new value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bfsp_update_MEMBER]
(   
    @IN_id INT = NULL,
    @IN_orig_id INT = NULL,

    @IN_flags INT = NULL,
    @IN_member_flags INT = NULL,
    @IN_role_flags INT = NULL,
    @IN_validation_flags INT = NULL,
    @IN_login_id VARCHAR(150) = NULL,
    @IN_email VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_password_crypt VARCHAR(65) = NULL


)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @iNewestIdentity as INT;


        /* convert '' to null on char and varchar cols */
        SET @IN_login_id = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(@IN_login_id)) = '' THEN NULL ELSE @IN_login_id END
        SET @IN_email = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(@IN_email)) = '' THEN NULL ELSE @IN_email END
        SET @IN_password_crypt = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(@IN_password_crypt)) = '' THEN NULL ELSE @IN_password_crypt END


        /* log the data */
        INSERT INTO MEMBERS
        (

            --ID,
            ORIG_ID, 
            SEQ, 
            SRC_MEMBER_ID, 
            FLAGS, 
            MEMBER_FLAGS, 
            ROLE_FLAGS, 
            VALIDATION_FLAGS, 
            LOGIN_ID, 
            EMAIL, 
            PASSWORD_CRYPT      
        ) 
        SELECT
            M.ORIG_ID, 
            M.SEQ + 1 SEQ, 
            M.SRC_MEMBER_ID, 
            ISNULL(@IN_flags, M.FLAGS) | 8 FLAGS, 
            ISNULL(@IN_member_flags, M.MEMBER_FLAGS) MEMBER_FLAGS, 
            ISNULL(@IN_role_flags, M.ROLE_FLAGS) ROLE_FLAGS, 
            ISNULL(@IN_validation_flags, M.VALIDATION_FLAGS) VALIDATION_FLAGS, 
            ISNULL(@IN_login_id, M.LOGIN_ID) LOGIN_ID, 
            ISNULL(@IN_email, M.EMAIL) EMAIL, 
            ISNULL(@IN_password_crypt, M.PASSWORD_CRYPT) PASSWORD_CRYPT
        FROM
            bfv_MEMBERS M
        WHERE
            M.FLAGS & 8 = 8 AND 
            M.ORIG_ID = @IN_orig_id
            --AND M.ID = @IN_id /* dont really need this right? e.g. can pass in orig_id and use that since it only looks for the current row */
        ;

        SET @iNewestIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


        /* set old row to inactive */
        UPDATE 
            MEMBERS
        SET 
            FLAGS = FLAGS &~ 8          
        WHERE
            ID = @IN_id /* need the id here as opposed to orig_id */
        ;


        RETURN


    END
```

Comment: So you are essentially trying to replicate the functionality provided by the functions `UPDATE()` and `COLUMNS_UPDATED()`, correct?

Comment: No, the procedure is called from an application. Example, a MEMBERS table. User can update their profile. Lets say the user wants to delete their middle name. They do so, and press update. the app detects that only that field changed, so it would call the stored procedure, only passing that single parameter in. all of the others default to NULL. But currently, the procedure above ignores any parameters which are NULL... to accommodate the only passing in of parameters from changed fields.

Comment: If your table(s) have nullable column(s), then you are trying to assign two meanings for the `NULL` value that is passed into the procedure. First meaning is: this parameter should be ignored. Second meaning: set the existing value of the column to `NULL`. Since a single parameter can't convey both meanings, you have to add an extra explicit parameter for each nullable column, such as `@IgnoreParameterABC bit`.

Comment: You could pass the old values for columns that aren't being changed.

Comment: @AndriyM - I am trying to avoid that because the tables could have >100 columns.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - Thanks for the suggestion... How would a solution like that look? I don't quite understand how one would implement that...

Comment: @robarwebservices, if your table has 100 nullable columns, then your procedure would have 200 parameters. First 100 parameters that contain the new values for each column (possibly `NULL` values). These parameters default to `NULL`. Second 100 parameters are just `bit` flags indicating whether procedure should use or ignore the corresponding parameter with value. The `bit` flags can default to "ignore". When calling such procedure you'll have to explicitly set parameters for those columns that are changing and their flags.

Comment: Looking at this from the database perspective, I can't really see why you are trying to avoid passing all the values. When you are inserting a new row, you are listing every column anyway. What am I missing? What specifically is the problem with passing every value?

Comment: @AndriyM - in the web application which calls the procedure, If i only want to update a few columns, I don't want to have to write lines of code to send in the many other columns which aren't involved. e.g. less overhead going to the db, and less code.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - that makes sense. Feel free to throw that into an answer, and I will accept.

Comment: ...moved clarifications to the question.

Comment: A variation on @Vladimir's suggestion would be to introduce just one additional parameter to specify which columns to update. It could be either a varbinary holding a bitmap (similar to COLUMNS_UPDATED) or a varchar/nvarchar holding the list of actual column names to update.

Comment: @robarwebservices, I don't want to put my comments into an answer, because I don't think this is the way how it should be done. I don't want to encourage this approach. The overall design seems to be not quite right. A table that has 100 columns is strange. I accept that it may be needed, but it is not common. Furthermore, 100 nullable columns is also strange. If it is really necessary to have 100 nullable columns, then I'd prefer to pass all 100 values for update. Otherwise, you'd have a lot of code both on the client and in DB for setting and checking the "ignore" flags for each parameter.